# Add transition to onClick div

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, css-transitions

I am trying to smoothen transition. when clicking on the section, it extends to display the text underneath. I would like to add a transition to this to make it slower and smoother.

I have attempted to do this by adding a transition to the "active" class but this is not good.

FYI - Still learning JS and advanced CSS so my knowledge is limited!

Thanks in advance!

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.third-last {
    width:28%;
    float: left;
}

.third {
    width: 28%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 85px;
}

.team-member {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition:3s;
    -webkit-transition:3s;
}

.content {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
      }
.team-role {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="third">
        <div class="team-member">
            <div class="collapsible">
                <img src="http://localhost/testsite/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/.jpg">
                <div class="team-role">
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">
            <div class="collapsible">
                <img src="http://text.jpg">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>Managing Director</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
        <div class="team-member">
            <div class="collapsible">
                <img src="http://localhost/testsite/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Charlie-Conway-Product-Designer-Simple-Design-Works.jpg">
                <div class="team-role">
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">
            <div class="collapsible">
                <img src="http://localhost/testsite/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Charlie-Conway-Product-Designer-Simple-Design-Works.jpg">
                <div class="team-role">
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third-last">
        <div class="team-member">
            <div class="collapsible">
                <img src="http://localhost/testsite/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Charlie-Conway-Product-Designer-Simple-Design-Works.jpg">
                <div class="team-role">
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>Managing Director</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member">
            <div class="collapsible">
                <img src="http:///testsite/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/.jpg">
                <div class="team-role">
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>Managing Director</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transition `display:none;` to `display:block;`
This is what i changed in your JS for it to work :

```
let teams = document.querySelectorAll(".team-member");
//note forEach is equal to your for(i ...) and the (team) is your "this" variable 
teams.forEach((team) => {
    let col = team.firstElementChild;
    let content = team.lastElementChild;

    let colH = col.clientHeight;
    let contentH = content.clientHeight;    
    team.style.height = `${colH}px`

    team.addEventListener("click", () => {

        if (team.style.height == `${colH}px`) {
      team.style.height = `${colH + contentH}px`
    } else {
      team.style.height = `${colH}px`
    }
    });
});
```

and also added `overflow:hidden;` to your team-member class
I recommend you to learn to use forEach functions they are much better than `for(i ...)`

Comment: Any Chance you could modify this and display?

https://jsfiddle.net/cobyfoster99/1zpn94jq/3/

Comment: i tried to do it with min height and max height but it didn't work so i had to change the JS and made this one https://codepen.io/DevKosov/pen/ExadVar this works for expanding the div but i can't get it to contract with plain javascript i got to go for now i might try later

Comment: nevermind i just forgot to add the == equality comparison *facepalm took 20mins to find here you go codepen.io/DevKosov/pen/ExadVar

Comment: Oh... I've done it this way - https://jsfiddle.net/g0cmph2q/2/

Is there a way I can minimise mine as it is very repetitive!

Comment: Yes i see how you've got it to work but it is not responsive at all because you have done it with static pixels in the other hand my code is shorter and works with different text font sizes or img size or any other changes so it'd be better if you use it. When you code in javascript you got to think smart solutions. I highly reccomend you to take the first freecodecamp course about javascript than take the 30 days challange of javascript from wes bos https://javascript30.com/

Comment: I was just going to use media queries for responsive but yes I see how yours works well. Is there a way of making it so you can only have one extended at a time? So if i click another one, the open one closes?

Comment: Ayy you're welcome glad it works :) and let me think about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206156/discussion-between-cobyfoster99-and-dev-kosov).

Answer (score 0):

display: none/block is not working with transitions. You should add style property by defauld opacity: 1; transition: .5s ease opacity; to your collapsible class.

```
.collapsible {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease 0.5s opacity;
}
.is-fadeout {
    opacity: 0; 
}
```

Add this .is-fadeout class onclick, and after timeout in 0.5s add property display none